# Помогите отредактировать предложение!

Tags: стилистика

"Прямые связи — это не только непосредственный контакт с его преимуществами" (мне кажется, слово "его" употреблено некорректно) в следующем тексте:

"В 80-е годы широкое развитие получили прямые связи между предприятиями мясной промышленности и сельским хозяйством. Их развитие способствовало экономии труда и сокращению потерь продукции на стадиях технологической цепи "производство — переработка — сбыт", а также сохраняло потребительскую стоимость мяса и мясных продуктов. **Прямые связи — это не только непосредственный контакт с его преимуществами.** Они означали прямое согласование производственных программ взаимосвязанных предприятий, прямое взаимное влияние друг на друга, объединение усилий на увеличение объема производства и улучшение качества продукции и т. д. При организации прямых связей в качестве заготовителя непосредственно выступали предприятия мясной промышленности и торговли. Они должны были взять на себя функции закупки скота в колхозах и совхозах и перевозку его специализированным транспортом."

Comment: Из правил этого сайта: Не благодарите автора ответа в комментариях. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. 
Если вы принимаете ответ, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В 80-е годы широкое развитие получили прямые связи между предприятиями мясной промышленности и сельским хозяйством. Их развитие способствовало экономии труда и сокращению потерь продукции **в технологической цепи** "производство — переработка — сбыт", а также **улучшало** потребительскую стоимость мяса и мясных продуктов.

Прямые связи — это не только непосредственный контакт производителей **со всеми  его преимуществами**. Такие связи означали прямое согласование производственных программ **взаимосвязанных предприятий, прямое влияние их друг на друга,** объединение усилий для увеличение объема производства и **повышение** качества продукции.

При организации прямых связей в качестве заготовителя непосредственно выступали предприятия мясной промышленности и торговли. Они **брали** на себя функции закупки скота в колхозах и совхозах и перевозку его специализированным транспортом

Comment: Предлагаю три улучшения: (1) "**повышало** потребительскую стоимость мяса и мясных продуктов". (2) "контакт **между** производителями со всеми его преимуществами"; (2) "объединение усилий **по** увеличению объема производства и повышению качества продукции" – М_Г 7

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Прямые связи - это не только непосредственный доступ к имеющимся у партнёра технологиям.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!